# How to get copied image in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uipasteboard

I know that when user makes for example image Copy in Photo Albums or Safari. Is there a way to get this image in my application programmatically?

Explain, please how to get this copied image.

Comment: why dont you compare images in your photo albums through code

Comment: Sorry, i do not understand you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was impressed founding such an easy and funny solution :)

```
UIImage *img = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard].image;
```